# Oracle - redo sequence number is different from oracle server's sequence number

Tags: oracle, logging, switch-statement, redo

I have an oracle database which has problems preventing it from opening.

To overcome the issues, I tried following steps:

First I mounted database:

```
SQL> startup mount;
ORA-32004: obsolete and/or deprecated parameter(s) specified
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1.2560E+10 bytes
Fixed Size          2171344 bytes
Variable Size        6878662192 bytes
Database Buffers     5670699008 bytes
Redo Buffers            8601600 bytes
Database mounted.
```

After that, I recovered database as below:

```
SQL> recover database until cancel;
ORA-00279: change 338584095 generated at 11/22/2016 08:41:55 needed for thread 1
ORA-00289: suggestion : /oracle/app/product/11g/db/dbs/arch1_9218_833801667.dbf
ORA-00280: change 338584095 for thread 1 is in sequence #9218


Specify log: {<RET>=suggested | filename | AUTO | CANCEL}
cancel
ORA-01547: warning: RECOVER succeeded but OPEN RESETLOGS would get error below
ORA-01194: file 1 needs more recovery to be consistent
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/oracle/app/oradata/ora11g/system01.dbf'


ORA-01112: media recovery not started
```

After this I tried to alter open database as below:

```
SQL> alter database open resetlogs;
alter database open resetlogs
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01194: file 1 needs more recovery to be consistent
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/oracle/app/oradata/ora11g/system01.dbf'
```

and finally I tried recovering system01 datafile as below:

```
SQL> recover datafile 1;
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-00314: log 2 of thread 1, expected sequence# 9218 doesn't match 9215
ORA-00312: online log 2 thread 1: '/oracle/app/oradata/ora11g/redo02.log'
```

as you can see in the final error "ORA-00314: log 2 of thread 1, expected sequence# 9218 doesn't match 9215" there is a sequence mismatch between the logfile redo02.log and the server.

How can this mismatch occur and what can I do to fix this?

PS: Since database cannot be opened, I cannot switch logfile and since redo02.log is the current logfile, I cannot drop or clean it.

```
SQL> select * from v$log;

    GROUP#    THREAD#  SEQUENCE#      BYTES    MEMBERS ARC STATUS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --- ----------------
FIRST_CHANGE# FIRST_TIME
------------- ------------------
     1      1          0   52428800      1 NO  UNUSED
    338564041 22-NOV-16

     3      1          0   52428800      1 NO  UNUSED
    338544000 22-NOV-16

     2      1       9218   52428800      1 NO  CURRENT
338584094 22-NOV-16
```